# Aws Lambda proxy integration POST request CORS issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cors

I'm trying to fix the cors issue when sending a request through my react frontend

I have a simple helloWorldFunction as my aws lambda

weirdly cors works with the get method but I'm stuck on the post

I have followed through this resource but it is not working for me.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Here is what the network tab looks like

[image]

**lambda code**

```js
export const lambdaHandler = async (event: APIGatewayProxyEvent): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
    try {
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: 'hello world',
            }),
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET"
            },
        };
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: 'some error happened',
            }),
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET"
            },
        };
    }
};
```

**template file**

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  sam-cors-test

  Sample SAM Template for sam-cors-test
  
# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello-world/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs18.x
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello 
            Method: post
    Metadata: # Manage esbuild properties
      BuildMethod: esbuild
      BuildProperties:
        Minify: true
        Target: "es2020"
        Sourcemap: true
        EntryPoints: 
        - app.ts

Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn
```

**Frontend fetch code**

```
const reqInfo = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
}

async function callFunction() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('https://oj0w78ftz4.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/', reqInfo);
        console.log(response);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

I'm confused why my post request isn't passing cors since I think it is a simple request.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests